# How can I uninstall a clustered SQL instance if the cluster has been destroyed?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, sql, failovercluster

First time going through this scenario, and apparently I did it very wrong.
On the DB servers I deleted the cluster group that held SQL and Reporting Services.
I then destroyed the cluster.
Then I tried to uninstall SQL.  No dice.  SQL still thinks its part of the non-existant cluster and will not let me uninstall it.  I went into the Maintenance menu of the SQL setup and tried to Remove Node...nope.

Unless I find a way out of this I will have to rebuild the OS if I can't get SQL off the box.

Comment: Bob, it is possible to manually rebuild the SQL cluster; I've done it before. This is the cleanest way to later uninstall it. I have to warn you that rebuilding is a tedious process. You may be better off doing a new OS install if you don't need the database. If you want to try restoring the database, please let me know and I can post instructions first thing in the morning. Plese tell me which version of Windows and SQL you are using so I can provide the appropriate steps.

Comment: I'm using SQL 2008 Standard.  I didn't care about the DB, and ended up reinstalling the OS (which is VMWare consequently since this is just a dev environment). I still wouldn't mind knowing how this rebuild works.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the folder named Cluster in registry and then uninstall SQL Server.

[image: Screenshot for above mentioned registry folder]